# Dart regex: how to replace matching substring with uppercase?

Tags: dart, text, replace

Replace all lowercase letter starting with underscore to uppercase. e.g.,

```
hello_world --> helloWorld
hello --> hello
today_is_monday -> todayIsMonday
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to define what you want *precisely* (which includes what you *don't* want).

Should every lower-case letter after a `_` be upper-cased, or only those where the `_` is preceded by a letter as well
That is, should `"_foo"` become `"Foo"` or not?

Let's assume you're translating snake-case to camel-case.

Then I'd probably still use a RegExp, and the answer to your question is [`replaceAllMapped`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.2/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html).

```dart
// RegExp matching a lower case letter preceded by 
// lower-case-letter-or-digit then underscore.
final _snakeRE = RegExp(r"(?<=[a-z\d])_([a-z])");
String snakeToCamelCase(String input) =>
    input.replaceAllMapped(_snakeRE, (m) => m[1]!.toUpperCase());
```

The RegExp `(?<=[a-z\d])_([a-z])` uses a *look-behind* (`(?<=...)`) to match an underscore and lower-case letter (`_([a-z])`) only if it follows a lower-case-letter-or-digit (`[a-z\d]`).
The look-behind is not part of the matched string, so only the following underscore and lower-case letter is matched.
That's important because the match is what the `replaceAllMapped` function replaces.

That means that in `"a b cd _e_f 9_g"`, only the "_f" and "_g" will be matched, and replaced by the letter upper-cased by the function ("F" and "G"), because the other letters are either not preceded by an underscore, or that underscore is not preceded by a letter-or-digit.

Comment: could you explain the regex  r"(?<=[a-z\d]_)[a-z]" ? thanks,

Comment: Added a description. And while doing so noticed that I forgot to remove the underscore when upper-casing, so fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replaceAllMapped function with a regular expression to grab a group and modify it.

```dart
void main() {
  const one = "hello_world";
  const two = "hello";
  const three = "today_is_monday";
  
  final regex = RegExp('_([a-z])');
  
  final oneResult = one.replaceAllMapped(regex, replaceUpperCase);
  final twoResult = two.replaceAllMapped(regex, replaceUpperCase);
  final threeResult = three.replaceAllMapped(regex, replaceUpperCase);
  
  print(oneResult);
  print(twoResult);
  print(threeResult);
}

String replaceUpperCase(Match match) {
  return match[1]?.toUpperCase() ?? match[0]!;
}
```

```
Output:
helloWorld
hello
todayIsMonday
```